# Change Size of Shell Ubuntu Server 16.04

Tags: 16.04, server

I'm running ubuntu server off of my laptop. Unfortunately, the screen is nonfunctional in one part.

[image]

I want to move my ubuntu server shell so that the text never writes to the nonfunctional part of the screen. I have tried to change the resolution in grub, but this just scales up a lower resolution to match my screen. How can I move my shell so it doesn't write to the broken part of my screen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see two options here. One is to simply run

```
stty cols 60
```

while assuming 60 is the number of characters you can see before they are obstructed by the broken screen. Change accordingly. Unfortunately that solution does not seem to work for all commands, but for most I tried.

Another options would be to run `tmux`. Then, give tmux the following command:

```
set-window-option force-width 60
```

Again, assuming 60 is the desired width. To enter a tmux command you have to type <kbd>ctrl-b</kbd> <kbd>:</kbd> first and then enter the command at the prompt that appears.